# How to plot time series stacked bar chart using plotly python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plotly-python

I have the following dataframe in pandas df_res, we can call it with a few rows as shown.

```
   date       time      weekday      team    recipient
 2019-08-30 14:49:22    Friday      team1   building308@list.com
 2019-08-30 05:57:51    Friday      team1   notification@listcom
 2019-08-29 22:54:58    Thursday    team1   robert.r@gmail.com
 2019-08-29 22:54:58    Thursday    team1   emcor@list.com
 2019-08-30 06:26:12    Friday      team1   building308@list.com
 2019-09-05 14:16:22    Thursday    team1   pqr@xyz.com
 2019-09-05 14:16:22    Thursday    team1   flash_hvac@list.com
 2019-09-04 22:54:59    Wednesday   team1   robert.r@gmail.com
 2019-09-04 22:54:59    Wednesday   team1   emcor@list.com
```

I want to plot a chart where the x-axis is a date ranging from June 2019 to Oct 2019. The y-axis is the count of how many times a recipient got an email in a given date. So I would like to do a stacked bar chart where each stack will be a recipient. For ex: on the date '2019-08-30', there are 2 mails for 'building308@list.com' and 1 for 'notification@listcom'. So I will have two stacks for that day. I also want to be able to provide a list of a few recipients whose email counts I am interested in. I wrote the below code to do the same but I'm struggling with how to get a count of the number of recipients. Instead if the count is a list or column, I am able to plot but that is not useful for me as the dataframe is huge with over a thousand rows.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import datetime


x = [datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=06, day=4),
 datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=11, day=5),
 datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=13, day=6)]
y = [2, 2, 5]

 fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(x=x, y=y)])
 # Use datetime objects to set xaxis range
 fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[datetime.datetime(2019, 06, 17),
                           datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 7)])
 fig.show()
```

UPDATED TO ADD CODE: 10/11/2019
    # plotting the values

```
    trace = go.Bar(
           x=[datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=8, day=1),
              datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=10, day=1)],
           y=[res_test['recipients'].value_counts()],
           name='Plot the values '
          )

      data = [trace]
      layout = go.Layout(title="Emails per volunteer", xaxis= 
                 {'title':'Date'}, yaxis={'title':'Email count'},
               barmode='stack'
                )


       fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
       py.iplot(fig)
```

Is this how I pass the value to the y-axis?

Answer (score 4):

#### Data preparation

```
date =['2019-08-30 14:49:22',
       '2019-08-30 05:57:51',
       '2019-08-29 22:54:58',
       '2019-08-29 22:54:58',
       ]
rec = ['building308@list.com','building308@list.com','emcor@list.com','pqr@xyz.com']
data = pd.DataFrame({
         'date':date,
         'recipient':rec
         })
```

#### Sample dataframe:

```
data
               date             recipient date_extract
0 2019-08-30 14:49:22  building308@list.com   2019-08-30
1 2019-08-30 05:57:51  building308@list.com   2019-08-30
2 2019-08-29 22:54:58        emcor@list.com   2019-08-29
3 2019-08-29 22:54:58           pqr@xyz.com   2019-08-29

# Extract date from date_timestamp
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data = data.assign(date_extract = [str(i.date()) for i in data['date']])
```

#### Get email count: Total emails per day

```
new_data = data.groupby(by=['date_extract','recipient']).size()
print(new_data)

date_extract  recipient           
2019-08-29    emcor@list.com          1
              pqr@xyz.com             1
2019-08-30    building308@list.com    2
```

As new_data is series you can directly pass it to x or y parameter in plotly.

#### Total Recipients

```
recipient_frequency = data['recipient'].value_counts()

# Recipient distribution
recipient_frequency
Out[]: 
building308@list.com    2
emcor@list.com          1
pqr@xyz.com             1
Name: recipient, dtype: int64

# Total recipient count
len(recipient_frequency)
Out[]: 3
```

if you have an issue with plotly - plots, refer some tutorials here: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python

Comment: Thank you so much! Most helpful - all the steps and the link with tutorials. I don't see a bar chart tutorial in your github. Maybe you could make this use case and provide one so it would be helpful. I updated my code to plot the values but although I am able to see date range in x-axis and email count in y-axis, nothing is plotted.

Comment: I have now added bar chart tutorial. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: I am sorry if it wasn't helpful. https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python/tree/master/Bar%20Chart I have created a new tutorial. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sayali. I appreciate the effort. I have solved my problem last week in a different way, I'll update the post in a little bit. But I'm sure your tutorial will be helpful for folks who read this page in search of help with plotly.

Comment: @py_noob By now you've gathered enough rep to award other users with your up-votes. If you found Sayalis efforts helpful, an up-vote is highly appreciated by most users. As a new user, using your up-votes even earns you a badge.